# ReactJs: Creating components from array leads to old props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of usernames `["frank", "john", "stevie"]`. looping through each element i create a **ChatBox** component:

```
{
  popups.map((x, i)=>(
    <ChatBox 
      addMessage={this.addMessage} 
      delMessage={this.delMessage} 
      setMessages={this.setMessages} 
      getMessages={this.getMessages} 
      name={x} 
      users={this.state.users} 
      id={x}
      key={i}
      user={this.fetchUser(x)}
    />
  ))
}
```

It looks pretty straight forward. I need to make an ajax call once the components are rendered, so I call this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props.name)
  //make ajax call using `this.props.name`
}
```

**The problem:** I noticed that the rendered components set the name props with the initial value of "frank" in `["frank", "john", "stevie"]`. i.e if I have five elements in the array, the last four components have an initial value of the first element in the array!. And its very important an ajax call is made once the component is rendered, but if the calls are made using the value of the first element in the array, the resulting components will all have the same data as the first component. that's flawed.

I tried `getDerivedStateFromProps()` and `componentDidUpdate()` but this looks hacky as the first component that is rendered has the correct value and rarely changes so the ajax call isn't made.

Is there a way I can have all rendered components to have the correct props so i can make the ajax call on `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure `popups` array contain the expected values and do not change afterwards. Also do all the components log `franky` ?

Comment: yes, I have got a logic that  sets popups..setStates({popus:[new array]}). when a user is clicked, a new name is appended and vice versa. and yes all components do log, but their initial state shows the value of the first element in the array.

Comment: I do'nt think you've posted enough code to figure out what's wrong. Each ChatBox, according to the code you posted, should have the correct name.

Comment: its quite a lengthy component, the ChatBox component has way more props than i posted here. but any insights as to why this might happen would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FrankDupree this might be happening as you are passing array index as the key value to the chatbox component. Try passing the itemName as key value for the ChatBox component.

```
    <ChatBox 
      addMessage={this.addMessage} 
      delMessage={this.delMessage} 
      setMessages={this.setMessages} 
      getMessages={this.getMessages} 
      name={x} 
      users={this.state.users} 
      id={x}
      key={x}
      user={this.fetchUser(x)}
    />
```

I think this might work for you.

Please go through: https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c for a better understanding.

Comment: oh my Lawd! you are a effing genius!! been stuck on this for days now. Thought it had to do with the props delaying the component or whatever. Thank you!!

Comment: Haha...react always warns about this :- Not giving array indexes as keys. We have another example now as to why it is so.